# discord.py command group that works as a normal command instead of doing the group name and command name

Tags: python, discord

I made a command group for my bot I was wondering if it's possible to make the commands in the group run as a normal command instead of having to do $games command name i want it to do $albums

I tried this

```
async def albums(ctx):
    def get_user_balance(user_id):
        c.execute("SELECT album_count FROM albums WHERE user_id = ?", (user_id,))
        result = c.fetchone()
        if result:
            return result[0]
        else:
            return 0
    
    balance = get_user_balance(ctx.author.id)
    await ctx.send(f"You currently have {balance} albums in your collection.")
```

#group

```
async def games(ctx):
    if ctx.invoked_subcommand is None:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="List of Games", description="Here are the available games:")
        embed.add_field(name="heist", value="Attempt to rob a concert and get away with the merch.", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="albums", value="Check the number of albums in your collection.", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="ab <amount>", value="Add albums to your collection.", inline=False)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```